# Given an angle a and vector v, what is the quaternion that represents that 3d rotation?

Tags: rotations, quaternions

And vice-versa, given a quaternion, what is the angle and vector that represents that rotation?

I've read [elsewhere](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/realNormedAlgebra/quaternions/transforms/derivations/vectors/index.htm) that a vector can be converted to a quaternion by `v_to_q : [x,y,z] -> (0, x, y, z)`.

So if on one hand I take a vector `v_0`, and rotate it about vector `v` by angle `a` to get vector `v_1`,

and on the other hand I take the  quaternion `v_to_q(v_0)`, and apply the same rotation in quaternion form (i.e. the quaternion represented by angle `a` and vector `v`),

then I should get the same quaternion as what `v_1` maps to: `v_to_q(v1)`. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quaternion product**

The quaternion product is defined like so:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathbf{p} \otimes \mathbf{q}  &= \left( p_0 + p_1 i + p_2 j + p_3 k\right) \left( q_0 + q_1 i + q_2 j + q_3 k\right)   \\
    &=   p_0q_0 + p_0q_1 i + p_0q_2 j + p_0q_3 k        \\
    & + p_1 q_0 i - p_1 q_1  + p_1 q_2 k - p_1 q_3 j      \\
    & + p_2 q_0 j - p_2 q_1 k - p_2 q_2  + p_2 q_3 i      \\
    & + p_3 q_0 k + p_3  q_1 j - p_3 q_2 i - p_3 q_3      \\
    &= ( p_0 q_0 - p_1 q_1 - p_2 q_2  - p_3 q_3)       \\
    &+ ({\color{blue} p_0q_1} + {\color{red}p_1 q_0} +  p_2 q_3 - p_3 q_2)i    \\
    &+ ({\color{blue} p_0 q_2} - p_1 q_3 + {\color{red} p_2 q_0} +  p_3  q_1)j   \\
    &+ ({\color{blue} p_0 q_3} + p_1 q_2 - p_2 q_1 + {\color{red}p_3 q_0})k
\end{split}   
\end{equation}
This can be simplified by writing $\mathbf{q} = (q_0, \vec{q})$, where $\vec{q}$ is the non-real part, $\vec{q} = q_1 \hat{i} + q_2 \hat{j} + q_3 \hat{k}$. This non-real part of the quaternion can be thought of as a vector, and its operations (dot and cross product) are defined similarly. Then, the result is
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{p} \otimes \mathbf{q} = (p_0 q_0 - \vec{p} \cdot \vec{q}, {\color{blue} p_0\vec{q}} + {\color{red} q_0\vec{p}} +  \vec{p}\times \vec{q})
\end{equation}
This is the so called Hamilton product. It is associative but not commutative.

If the quaternions are thought of as $4 \times 1$ matrices ($\mathbf{q} = \left[q_0, q_1, q_2, q_3 \right]^T$), the multiplication of two quaternions can be carried out by the following matrix product :

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathbf{p} \otimes \mathbf{q} &= \underbrace{
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
  % This is the correct matrix
p_0 & -p_1 & -p_2 & -p_3    \\
p_1 & p_0 & -p_3 & p_2    \\
p_2 & p_3 & p_0 & -p_1    \\
p_3 & -p_2 & p_1 & p_0    \\
\end{array}
\right]}_{=P}
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
q_0  \\
q_1  \\
q_2  \\
q_3  \\
\end{array}
\right]    \\
&= 
{\color{blue} p_0 }
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
q_0  \\
{\color{blue} q_1 }  \\
{\color{blue} q_2 }  \\
{\color{blue} q_3 }  \\
\end{array}
\right]
+
\left[
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
0 & -p_1 & -p_2 & -p_3    \\
\hline
{\color{red} p_1} & 0 & -p_3 & p_2    \\
{\color{red} p_2} & p_3 & 0 & -p_1    \\
{\color{red} p_3} & -p_2 & p_1 & 0    \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
q_0  \\
q_1  \\
q_2  \\
q_3  \\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

**Some additional definitions**

Let us define the quaternion conjugate and norm (modulus) as follows:
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{q}^* = (q_0, -\vec{q})
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \left| \mathbf{q} \right| = \sqrt{q_0^2 + q_1^2 + q_2^2 + q_3^2}
\end{equation}
Now we see that
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{q} \otimes \mathbf{q}^* = (q_0^2 + \left| \mathbf{q} \right|^2, 0)
 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad
 \frac{1}{q_0^2 + \left| \mathbf{q} \right|^2} \mathbf{q} \otimes \mathbf{q}^* = (1,0) = 1
\end{equation}
Consequently, every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse and the system of quaternions is a skew field. Furthermore, the norm of the (quaternion) product of two quaternions equals the product of their norms. This means that the product of two unit quaternions is also a unit quaternion.

The inverse of the rotation quaternion is the same as its conjugate:
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{r}^{-1} = \mathbf{r}^*
\end{equation}
The quaternion product of two unit conjugates is the conjugate of the product the other way around:
\begin{equation}\
\begin{split}
\mathbf{r}_1^{*} \otimes \mathbf{r}_2^{*}  &= (r_{10}, \vec{r}_1) \times (r_{20}, \vec{r}_2) \\
      &= (r_{10} r_{20} - \vec{r_1} \cdot \vec{r_2} , - r_{10}\vec{r}_2 - r_{20}\vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2 \times \vec{r}_1) \\
      &= \left(\mathbf{r}_2 \otimes \mathbf{r}_1 \right)^{*}         \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

**Vector rotations with quaternions**

Define a vector quaternion $(0,\vec{v}) = \mathbf{v}$ and a rotation quaternion $\mathbf{r} = (\cos{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}, \sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \vec{r})$ for some unit vector $\vec{r}$. Now we can calculate the conjugation of $\mathbf{v}$ by $\mathbf{r}$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathbf{r} \star \mathbf{v}   &= \mathbf{r} \otimes \mathbf{v} \otimes \mathbf{r}^*  = \mathbf{r} \otimes (0,\vec{v}) \otimes (\cos{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}, - \sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \vec{r})           \\
   &= \mathbf{r} \otimes (0 + \vec{v} \cdot  \sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \vec{r} , 0 + \cos{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \vec{v} + \vec{v}\times (- \sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \vec{r}))       \\
   &= \mathbf{r} \otimes (\sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}\vec{v} \cdot   \vec{r} , \cos{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \vec{v} + \sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}\vec{r}\times   \vec{v})        \\
   &= (\cos{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}, \sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2} \vec{r}}) \otimes (\sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}\vec{v} \cdot   \vec{r} , \cos{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \vec{v} + \sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}\vec{r}\times   \vec{v})  \\
   &= (\cos{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}\sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}\vec{v} \cdot   \vec{r} - (\sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2} \vec{r}})\cdot(\cos{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \vec{v} + \sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}\vec{r}\times   \vec{v}),  \\
   & \cos{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}(\cos{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \vec{v} + \sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}\vec{r}\times   \vec{v}) + (\sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}\vec{v} \cdot   \vec{r} )(\sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2} \vec{r}}) + (\sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2} \vec{r}}) \times (\cos{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \vec{v} + \sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}\vec{r}\times   \vec{v}))   \\
   &= (\cos{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}\sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}\vec{v} \cdot   \vec{r} - \cos{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2} \vec{r}} \cdot \vec{v} - \sin^2{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \vec{r} \cdot(\vec{r}\times   \vec{v}),  \\
   & \cos^2{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \vec{v} + \cos{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}\sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}\vec{r}\times   \vec{v} + \sin^2{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}(\vec{v} \cdot   \vec{r} )\vec{r} + \sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2} \cos{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \vec{r}} \times  \vec{v} +  \sin^2{\tfrac{\theta}{2} \vec{r}} \times (\vec{r}\times   \vec{v}))   \\
   &= (0,  \\
   & \cos^2{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \vec{v} +  \sin^2{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}(\vec{v} \cdot   \vec{r} )\vec{r} + 2\sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \cos{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \vec{r} \times  \vec{v} +  \sin^2{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \vec{r} \times (\vec{r}\times   \vec{v}))   \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Additionally, it is known that $\vec{r} \times ( \vec{r} \times \vec{v}) = (\vec{r} \cdot \vec{v})\vec{r} - (\vec{r} \cdot \vec{r}) \vec{v} = (\vec{r} \cdot \vec{v})\vec{r} - \vec{v} \Rightarrow \sin^2{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}(\vec{r} \cdot \vec{v})\vec{r} = \sin^2{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}\vec{r} \times ( \vec{r} \times \vec{v}) + \sin^2{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}\vec{v}$, resulting in
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{r} \star \mathbf{v} = \vec{v} + 2\sin{\tfrac{\theta}{2} \cos{\tfrac{\theta}{2}}} \vec{r} \times  \vec{v} +  2\sin^2{\tfrac{\theta}{2}} \vec{r} \times (\vec{r}\times   \vec{v})
\end{equation}
or the so called Euler-Rodrigues formula for rotation. The resulting vector quaternion $\mathbf{v}^{'} = (0,\vec{v}^{'})$ represents the rotation of $\vec{v}$ around an arbitrary vector $\vec{r}$ by angle $\theta$ to produce the rotated vector $\vec{v}^{'}$.

Comment: What an amazing answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your last question is a straight **yes**.

As for your first question, suppose we have an angle $\theta$ and unit axis vector $v$ represented as an imaginary quaternion. Then the rotation quaternion is simply
$$
  q = e^{\theta v/2} = \cos\theta/2 + v\sin\theta/2
$$
and it rotates a vector (imaginary quaternion) $w$ via
$$
  w \mapsto qw\bar q
$$
where $\bar q$ is the conjugate. Notice that $-q$ represents the same rotation, so in general we cannot distinguish between $\pm q$ without further conventions.

It should be clear now that given a rotation quaternion $q = q_0 + q_i$ where $q_0$ is a scalar and $q_i$ is the imaginary part that the axis and angle could be given by
$$
  v = \frac{q_i}{|q_i|},\quad \tan\theta/2 = \frac{|q_i|}{q_0}
$$
where $|q_i| = \sqrt{\bar q_iq_i}$. Minor variations are possible because of the aformentioned equivalence between $q$ and $-q$ as well as whether we want $v$ or $-v$.